# customize organize import in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I am using organize import in eclipse and this is one of the best features of eclipse.

But can i customize organize import the way i want to.

**Ex.**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```

But I want it to be something like this.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```

It organizes opening brace in same line as function. But I want it to be at the next line.

**Can I customize to have this opening bracket in next line ?** So whenever I do organize import it automatically changes to opening bracket in the next line.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this with the `Source > Format` command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, on a Mac this is <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>).

How the code is formatted is set in `Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter`. Edit an existing profile or create a new one and look at the `Braces` section.

You can set formatting to be done automatically when you save a file in `Preferences > Java > Editor > Save Actions`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean "format code" instead of organize import.

You can achieve what you want easily:

click on

```
window > preferences
```

and then

```
Java > Code Style > Formatter
```

Eclipse has base formatters that you cannot modify. However you can copy them and modify them to create your own based on the default eclipse included ones.

You need to create yours and then edit it.

under the tab "braces" you'll find what you want